# NestJS Websocket-Server not reachable on Production

Tags: websocket, deployment, socket.io, apache2, nestjs

when I'm running the following code locally, everything works perfectly. my client is able to connect to the websocket-server.

when deploying the app in a docker container on the server, i cannot establish the socker-io connection.

nestjs itself is running perfectly.
im using @nestjs/current --latest with the socket-io module.

the production-server is running on debian10.

app.gateway.ts

```js
@WebSocketGateway({
  transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
  },
})
export class AppGateway .......
```

app.module.ts

```js
@Module({
  ...
  providers: [AppService, ErrorService, AppGateway],
  ...
})
```

Apache2 config:

```sh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=polling    [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*)           http://127.0.0.1:3000/$1 [P,L]

ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
ProxyPass / ws://127.0.0.1:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / ws://127.0.0.1:3000/
```

Dockerfile

```
....
EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "node", "./dist/main.js" ]
```

Docker start command

```sh
$ docker run -d -p 3000:3000 container-name
```

Error i get on the client side:

```sh
error: "Not Found"
message: "Cannot GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NrIrg-F"
statusCode: 404
```

I don't know what to do anymore. Already tested a lot of configuration options in apache2, using a different port in the websockets-instance and so on. help.